# how do I jump to a function definition in emacs when using slime?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp

I have installed slime using https://github.com/thephoeron/slime-pack and want to explore the common-lisp a bit more.

How do I access the source for a particular function in emacs?

for example, if I have a function:

```
(type-of 1)
```

and I want to visit the source of `type-of`, how can this be done?

Comment: I don't use the library you referenced, but I do use `M-x find-function` quite frequently.  Does that work for you?  There is also `find-function-other-window` and `find-function-other-frame`.

Comment: I had the error `Directory /usr/bin/src/code` does not exist, create it ?` but it worked after I installed Slime with Emacs' package manager.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<kbd>Meta</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>

It calls the function: `slime-edit-definition`

For jumping to functions inside your lisp implementation you may need to do something extra to point to the sources. In SBCL you have to `sb-ext:set-sbcl-source-location` to the correct place in `.sbclrc`:

```
(sb-ext:set-sbcl-source-location "/path/to/sbcl/")
```

You can edit `.sbclrc` with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> `~/.sbclrc` in Emacs.

Comment: If you build SBCL yourself the source location is set automatically.

Comment: This only works if the function was defined in a file you loaded. If you tey to do this with a definition you've sent to the REPL from your source via C-x e, you'll get `Error: DEFINITION-SOURCE of function FOO-BAR did not contain meaningful information.`

Comment: But, how to jump back?

Comment: META comma allows you jump back

Comment: Link to [the Slime doc](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Finding-definitions.html) :)

Comment: And if the respective function is in a package, don’t forget to load that package in the REPL. Took me 5 minutes to realize this, I had just started Emacs.