# How can I view the definition of a function in lisp (sbcl)?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I use `sbcl+emacs+slime`.
I writing a function in lisp,
I use `C-c C-c` compile, but i've already deleted it.
I can't find it. I want to know how I define it.

I tried use `function-lambda-expression`, but I get this:

```
(function-lambda-expression #'b)
T
B
```

I hope someone can give me some help.Thanks very much in advance!

---

Thanks Vsevolod.
If function define in `repl`, i can use `(descri #'function-name)` get how i define the function, but if i through `C-c C-c` define it, i just get `source file`

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRUGG.gif)

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, but it may answer your question: [how do I jump to a function definition in emacs when using slime?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24818321/1281433).  If you have the distribution source installed, that may work. [implementations of lisp functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33141286/1281433) isn't a great question, but it might help, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on your settings for debug and optimization you may be able to get it via `describe`:

```
CL-USER> (defun f (a) (print a))
F
CL-USER> (describe #'f)
#<FUNCTION F>
  [compiled function]

Lambda-list: (A)
Derived type: (FUNCTION (T) (VALUES T &OPTIONAL))
Source form:
  (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA F
      (A)
    (BLOCK F (PRINT A)))
```

You can see the definition here in the `Source form` part.